# Does per-pixel viewing zenith angle (VZA) is identical between landsat sensors for a common path/row?

Tags: remote-sensing, landsat

Due to the distance from the nadir viewing vector of the satellite, variation in viewing zenith angle (VZA) is observed from the center to the outer edges of the scene (as shown in figure one).[image: Figure 1 : Landsat 8 OLI Zenith Sensor Viewing Angle Band for 163/047 Band 6 acquired on 2014 Day 175 (https://www.usgs.gov/land-resources/nli/landsat/solar-illumination-and-sensor-viewing-angle-coefficient-files?qt-science_support_page_related_con=1#qt-science_support_page_related_con)]

Because Landsat 5 TM, 7 ETM+ and 8 OLI all have a field of view of 15° (±7.5° from nadir) I was wondering if I can expect changes in pixel-based VZA over the entire Landsat time series for a given path/row, or if it is constant. And if it's constant, it is within sensors only or also between sensors ?

Furthermore, Is it expected to have a difference between bands for a same scene ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A response to myself in case some one have the same question.
Yes the per-pixel viewing zenith angle (VZA) remain the same between scenes for a same sensor. Nonetheless, there is differencies between bands, and there is difference between sensors.